# How to update projection of layers in Geoserver using gsconfig

Tags: python, geoserver, coordinate-system, layers, geoserver-rest-api

Im using following code to find projection of layer

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog 
cat=Catalog("http:// localhost:8080/geoserver/rest") 
myResource = cat.get_resources(store='storeName', workspace='workspaceName')
layers = cat.get_layers(myResource)
for layer in layers:
    layer.projection
```

I found that few layers are having projection "None". How can I update those layers projection with "EPSG:4326" using gs config.

Comment: Can you guarantee that all the data is in EPSG:4326?

Comment: yes..all of layers had "EPSG:4326"

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to set the srs property of the layer

```
layer.srs = "EPSG:4326"
layer.native_crs = "EPSG:4326"
```

Comment: Thanks for information. I have tried as above and saved as follow  cat.save(layer) but it's not saving the layer.what can I do next?

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to change this on the resource level:

```
layer=cat.get_layer("layer_name")
resource=layer.resource
resource.projection='EPSG:4326'
cat.save(resource)
cat.save(layer)
cat.reload()
```